# Inverse in Tensor Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, rough-path-theory

I'm trying to prove Exercise 1.7 from [Rough Path Theory](https://researchers.ms.unimelb.edu.au/%7Exgge@unimelb/Files/Notes/Rough%20Path%20Theory.pdf) which states any $\xi=(1,\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_N) \in T^N(V)$ has an inverse and the following holds
$$ \xi\, \otimes\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n(\xi-\mathbf{1})^{\otimes n}=\mathbf{1} \tag{1}$$
where is the unit $\mathbf{1}\triangleq(1,0,\cdots,0) \in T^N(V)$.

$T^N(V)$ is the $N$-th truncated tensor algebra over the real vectorspace $V$ and is defined by
$$T^N(V) \triangleq \bigoplus_{n=0}^N V^{\otimes n}=\{\xi=(1,\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_N) : \xi_n \in V^{\otimes n} ,0\leq n\leq N\}$$
with the convention $V^{\otimes 0}\triangleq\mathbb{R}$.

The 1. question is how to prove $(1)$? My attempts will follow.

The 2. question is does $V^{\otimes 0}\triangleq\mathbb{R}$ imply $v^{\otimes 0}=\mathbf{1}$ for $v \in V$ especially for $v=0$? Only if assume so I'm able to prove it for $N=0,1,2,3$.

$\mathbf{My Attempts}:$

I calculated $(1)$ for $N=1,2,3$. Thereby I realized
$$(\xi-\mathbf{1})^{\otimes n}=(\underbrace{0,\cdots,0}_{n \, times},\star,\cdots\star) \tag{2}$$
and can also proof this. From there on I can also proof that
$$\Big(\xi\, \otimes\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n(\xi-\mathbf{1})^{\otimes n}\Big)_{l=1}=1.$$
What is left is that for $1<l\leq N$
$$\Big(\xi\, \otimes\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n(\xi-\mathbf{1})^{\otimes n}\Big)_{l>1}=0.$$
One way to prove it might be to figure out the $\star$ part of $(2)$ and continue via induction. I think it'll work but looks like a lot of work for this result what looks to me like a standard result. I tried the straightforward way and got
\begin{align*}
\Big(\xi\, \otimes\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n(\xi-\mathbf{1})^{\otimes n}\Big)_{l}&=\sum_{k=0}^l \xi_k \otimes \Big(\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n (\xi-\mathbf{1})^{\otimes n}\Big)_{l-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^l \sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n \xi_k \otimes \Big((\xi-\mathbf{1})^{\otimes n}\Big)_{l-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^l \sum_{n=0}^{l-k} (-1)^n \xi_k \otimes \Big((\xi-\mathbf{1})^{\otimes n}\Big)_{l-k}
\end{align*}
where I'm stuck.

Comment: Every element in your algebra can be written uniquely in the form x = a+w, with w a sum of homogeneous elements of positive degree. If a=0, then x^N = w^N = 0, so x is not invertible. If not, then x is a(1+w/a) and you should check that the inverse of x is a^{-1}(1-w/a+w^2/a^2-w^3/a^3+...): To do that, simply multiply and check that you get 1.

Comment: The *only* thing you need to do this calculation is that w^N is zero, btw, so it is better to try to forget as much of the concrete details of your situation as is possible.